# Can I get another Flameblade or repair the one I've got?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

After some random side-quest, I found the Flameblade.  Best weapon I'd seen by far and looks super cool.  Not wanting to break it, I've avoided using it in hopes that I would eventually find someone that can repair damaged weapons.  My hopes of finding someone like that are rapidly diminishing.

So, is there a way to keep my Flameblade (and other fancy weapons like it) from breaking?  If not, can I go back to the place I found it and get another one?  If so, when would it respawn?

Comment: In a side-quest? I found mine just laying in a garbage pile. (We're talking about the "Great Flameblade" right?)  Head to the Ancient Tree Stump in the west side of Hyrule Field. That's where I found mine.

Comment: @JeffMercado Nope, I'm talking about the Flameblade.  The Great Flameblade appears to be a different sword.

Comment: Ok, I'm assuming the Flameblade is the 1-handed variant. The Great Flameblade I'm thinking of is 2-handed.  But it's all the same to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't look like you're getting a solid response on how to get these weapons again. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTftOMv-iRk) shows where the Flameblade and the Great Flameblade respawns.

Spoilers, obviously.

To summarise, you go to an area called Eldin Great Skeleton. You will find this northwest of the Death Mountain, and right above Eldin Mountains. A group of tough enemies there have these weapons and they respawn after a blood moon --- so you can get an infinite amount of these, provided you can defeat them.

[image: Map showing where the Eldin Great Skeleton is]

Comment: Excellent!  Unfortunately it looks like a difficult encounter.

Comment: You might want to add that they are stupid too. You can get up on top of the skeleton's spine, set your round bombs down, let them fall into camp, and blow them up (multiple times). They will never figure out what was attacking them (if you are careful).

Comment: @BrainStorm.exe, yeah I did it that way once ... I gave up after 10min (and a gazzillion bombs), the monsters still had half of their HP left so I had to get down there and finish them by hand ...

Answer (score 8):

[image: "The Complete Official Guide" pg. 348]

A great way to repair any tool, including rusted ones, is to throw it at a Rock Octorok when it's sucking in air. It will spit it back out at you fresh and clean. It's official and in the guide, so it's not exploiting or cheating. The Flameblade is a personal favorite weapon of mine too. ^_^

Comment: So it has to be rock octoroks. I'd been trying with water and grass ones with no luck.

Comment: I just cannot believe this is the official way.  Nintendo implements weird game mechanics...

Comment: This says it's for "rusty" weapons. Does it repair non-rusty weapons too?

Answer (score 6):

[Various sources](http://twinfinite.net/2017/03/zelda-breath-of-the-wild-how-to-repair-weapons/) are saying that there isn't a way to repair weapons.  Part of the games strategy is to rotate out weapons so you can make them last longer.

> Unfortunately, switching weapons constantly is part of the challenge and strategy of The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild. Because of this, you can’t repair weapons so they will all explode eventually

**However**, there appears to be one way to repair items, though I believe this is not a legit way and likely will be patched as it sounds more like an exploit.  Nonetheless, one user on [GameFAQS](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/632936-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75066830/874377167) discovered that Octorok enemies can suck up items and after being killed, will drop them again fully repaired:

> There is a way to repair them.
>
> The octorok enemies that suck in air before they shoot can also suck in items. If they suck in your weapons and you kill them they will drop your weapons back with full durability.

Someone also stated on that thread that doing this cleans the rust of weapons as well.

Comment: That's a nice bit of info.  I'd also like to know if weapons not dropped by enemies ever respawn (for example the Flamesword mentioned in the question comes from a random chest).

Comment: Do chests ever close again? If they don't I would say no.  Searching now for a definite answer but little information is available.

Comment: It's not a bug or exploit; try throwing a **Rusty Broadword** or similar rotten weapon at an Octorok sometime...

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I don't own the game :D.  But to me it just sounds like an exploit.

Comment: The Octorok repair method is not a bug, it is stated in the guide as an official way to repair a weapon or turn a rusty weapon into a new one.

Comment: I get what he's saying,  if rusty swords come out normal, it may be a feature not a bug.  Or possibly a partially bugged feature.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a concrete location, but you can certainly get another Flameblade. Several mechanics in the game can facilitate this:

- You found it in a monster chest in the world. This means that when the Blood Moon rolls around, you can re-open the chest.
- You found it on the floor. Some items (the Silver Longsword in Zora's Domain comes to mind) always respawn after a period of time, or after re-entering the area.

Comment: The Flameblade I found was behind 2 bombable walls near Toto Sah Shrine. It's been 3 blood moons since I first found it and the chest is not there anymore.

Comment: Those are not the type of chest I mean - I'm referring to the ones where the chests activate after clearing a camp of monsters.

Answer (score 3):

Many of the answers on this page are kind of a roundabout way to find those.  The most reliable place I've found for elemental weapons is described in [my answer here on another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/312134/where-can-frostblades-respawn/312173#312173).  There is a map in that answer.  You can find electric, ice, and fire weapons in the form of spears, swords, and great swords in the Coliseum just north-west of the Great Plateau.

Answer (score 0):

-Treasure Chest in Saas Ko'sah Shrine in the Central Hyrule Region

-Treasure Chest in Voo Lota Shrine in the Tabantha Region

-Treasure Chest in Korsh O'hu Shrine in the Wasteland Region

-Treasure Chest in Tutsuwa Nima Shrine in the Akkala Region

All of the shrines above have a flamelade as a reward but don't respawn. A good respawn place is in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTftOMv-iRk).

Answer (score 0):

Also, I'm not sure how reliable this really is because I just did it, if you drop the damaged weapon and then go into an inn, when you wake up it should be undamaged. That is probably just a bug but it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

A Great flame blade is next to the shrine in Hyrule castle, Along with 3 lizards with steal bows. Also One is in the Northeast labyrinth right below Tu Ka'loh's shrine, on the staircase in the main building with the the shrine a side hole has burnable brambles blocking the blade at the end of the winding hallway. A better blade, the royal broadsword is stuck in the top of the skull on top of woodland Tower, though it doesn't burn things. All three of these replenish with the blood moon.

Answer (score -1):

There is one way to keep a weapon in the game, but it is expensive, but worth it if you like how a weapon looks. This also comes with some perks. First, go to Hateno village and start the 'hylian homeowner' side quest. You can start by travelling southwest of the myahm agana shrine and crossing the bridge. Go around the back of the house and talk to Bolson. After agreeing, gather 30 bundles of wood from the midla woods and get 3000 rupees from somewhere. Talk to bolson again and he will let you have the house, with a weapon display inside. Equp the flameblade and press A next to the weapon display. Sure, you cant use it, but you can look at it and be assured it wont break.

But thats stupid, just keep using them and get them back from the eldin great skeleton