# What equipment is unique?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

What gear in the game is unique, in that you can only ever obtain one of them (at a time) in the game?

I only know about the following items:

- Master Sword - recharges instead of breaking
- Champion weapons - can break like any other weapon, but an NPC near where you obtained each one will make you a new one in exchange for some materials.
- Hylian Shield - I'm unsure about this one

Are there any other unique weapons, bows, or shields in the game that you can't get another of once their durability runs out?

I found a cool Frostspear in a shrine but I'm hesitant to use it unless I know I can get another one later on.

Comment: There's the light bow from Zelda during the final battle although you only have that temporarily so I'm not sure if you want to count that.

Comment: Admittedly the Hylian Shield *can* break, although it has much more durability than any other shield.

Comment: @Fatalize How much more durability?

Comment: @Pyritie various sites suggest that it has 800 durability.

Comment: @Seiyria And how much do most regular shields have?

Comment: @Pyritie no idea, but I'd wager significantly less.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/302277/42984

Comment: @Pyritie To put 800 into perspective, the next most durable shield has a durability of about 40.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following items can only be obtained in one way:

- Master Sword
- Hylian Shield
- All the Champion weapons
- Cerimonial Spear
- Rubber Armour Set
- Barbarian Armour Set
- Climbing Armour Set
- Zora Armour Set
- Old Shirt
- Old Trousers
- Snow Boots
- Sand Boots
- Thunder Helm
- > "Of the Wild Armour Set"

All items that can only be obtained in one place (except the Nintendo Switch Shirt) and don't respawn can be re-obtained either by remaking them (in the case of the Champion weapons), or can be purchased from a special store.

Spoilers for the store:

> You must complete the quest "From the Ground Up", which is unlocked after purchasing the house in Hateno Village. After you've fully built the town, and NPC will spawn on the roof of the building right of the entrance of Tarry Town. Speak to him. He can sell anything that can only be normally obtained once in the game, bar the Master Sword, Cerimonial Spear, and Champion Weapons

Comment: In my game this special store don't sell weapons of any type. Only wereables that are obtenible as a reward on shrines.

Comment: @Grirg Updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz It's not re-craftable, it's re-purchasable.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz In the context of this game, no. Recraftable specifically refers to the fact that an NPC recrafts the weapon if you provide him the raw materials, with no monetary fee. Repurchasable means that it is purchased purely for Rupees and requires nothing else to re-obtain.

Comment: @SGR fair enough

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, the only item that cannot be re-obtained is the Master Sword. To accommodate this, it is not droppable and [has a different way of handling durability](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302967/how-does-the-master-sword-durability-work).

All other items are re-obtainable (although you can't necessarily have multiple at a time). To your examples:

- Champion weapons can be re-gotten with a diamond and some other materials
- The Hylian Shield can be re-bought somewhere in the game if it breaks after being found initially
- the Frost Spear can be found in the Coliseum Ruins, supposedly, so this is likely not a unique item.

The Ceremonial Trident also can only have one instance in the world at a time, as well.

Comment: Frost spear? Why is that unique?